# Convert String list to sorted Map String length as key

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<String>` and I have to convert it to `Map`, by grouping same length `String`s into a `List`, using `String` length as the key in, sorted order. It can be done using -

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();
for (String str : list) {
    if (!result.containsKey(str.length())) {
        result.put(str.length(), new ArrayList<>());
    }
    result.get(str.length()).add(str);
}
```

How can we do it using Java 8 streams?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues did you run into? Have you tried looking up your problem before posting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with streams:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        String::length,        // use length of string as key
        TreeMap::new,          // create a TreeMap
        Collectors.toList())); // the values is a list of strings
```

This collects the stream by means of the overload of [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) that accepts 3 arguments: the key mapper function, the supplier of the map and the downstream collector.

However, there's a more compact way to do it, without streams:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new TreeMap<>();
list.forEach(s -> result.computeIfAbsent(s.length(), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s));
```

This uses [`List.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) and [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 10):

Java streams can be grouped into a map by using the grouping collectors, the easiest way to make one is to use

`Collectors.groupBy(comparator)`

where comparator converts streamed values into map keys.

The return is a Map from comparator key to list of entries

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    List<String> in = Arrays.asList("A", "AB", "B", "ABC");
    final Map<Integer, List<String>> all = in.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
    System.out.println(all);
  }
}
```

Output:

`{1=[A, B], 2=[AB], 3=[ABC]}`

Comment: I had JDK 9 set as my default in my IDE, I have changed `List.of` to `Arrays.asList`, to make my answer compatible with Java 8

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Java 8 with groupingBy on one line.

```
result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
```