# How to Map a String stream by length

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I got a stream of Strings and want to map them by Length

```
 Stream<String> s = Stream.of("aaaa", "a", "aaa", "a", "aaaa", "aa", "aaaaaa", "aa");
 Map<Integer, Set<String> result = null;
 int i = 0;
 result.put(i, s.filter(x -> (x.length() == i));
```

Obviously, that won't work this way because I can't open the stream multiple times and I cant access the longes String for a nice loop. But how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String list to sorted Map String length as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900018/convert-string-list-to-sorted-map-string-length-as-key)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the Java8 solution to your problem,

```
final Map<Integer, Set<String>> strByLength = s
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, Collectors.toSet()));
```